# How to make synchronous DNS requests in a nodejs script?

Tags: node.js, dns

I need to make synchronous DNS requests in my NodeJS program, using a specific DNS server (I need actual requests, no lookup). I would like to use the standard DNS library if possible. My code works in interactive mode but not in the actual script. I'm not very comfortable with sync issues so I don't fully understand what await and stuff actually do.

Here is my code, currently in my script:

```
var readline = require('readline-sync');

async function sendm(req, srv) {
    console.log("Will ask " + srv.getServers()[0] + " for " + req);
    const addresses = await srv.resolve4(req);
    console.log(addresses);
}
```

That function is executed when the user inputs something starting with "s":

```
const { Resolver } = require('dns').promises;
const dns = new Resolver();
dns.setServers(["8.8.8.8"]);
// ...

var input = "";
while(input != "q") {
        input = readline.question("Command: ");
        if(/^s/g.test(input)) { // input starts with s
                console.log("Input starts with s");
                sendm("stackoverflow.com", dns);
        }
        else if(/^r/g.test(input))
                console.log("input starts with r");
        // ...
}
```

Here is an output:

```
# nodejs debug.js
Command: s
Input starts with s
Will ask 8.8.8.8 for stackoverflow.com
Command: s
Input starts with s
Will ask 8.8.8.8 for stackoverflow.com
Command: s
Input starts with s
Will ask 8.8.8.8 for stackoverflow.com
Command: r
input starts with r
Command: r
input starts with r
Command: s
Input starts with s
Will ask 8.8.8.8 for stackoverflow.com
Command: q
[ '151.101.1.69', '151.101.65.69', '151.101.129.69', '151.101.193.69' ]
[ '151.101.1.69', '151.101.65.69', '151.101.129.69', '151.101.193.69' ]
[ '151.101.1.69', '151.101.65.69', '151.101.129.69', '151.101.193.69' ]
[ '151.101.1.69', '151.101.65.69', '151.101.129.69', '151.101.193.69' ]
```

I need to process the DNS addresses while the program is still running. How could I do? I've tried different things I found on the DNS library documentation but nothing worked. Could you please help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being an async function, sendm returns a promise, but the while loop just starts again because it is not aware of promises and you can send a new request while the other is suspended on it's await call.
While [top level await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) is not yet shipped with node you can wrap the whole thing in an async IIFE which will properly wait for your dns call.

```
(async () => {
        var input = "";
        while(input != "q") {
                // ...
                        await sendm("stackoverflow.com", dns);
                // ...
        }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to make your while loop wait on the return of your function `sendm` I think you can put `async` before the while loop and then `await` before your function, although instead of storing the result in `addresses` it should be returned by the function (sendm) that way it will return a resolved promise and only then continue. If you cant wrap the while in async just stick it in a function and put the await before the function call to `sendm`.
To be clear, `async` means the function is executed asynchronously, `await` means that it returns a resolved promise and will not continue execution until it reached that state of resolution. So it's kind of like having blocking synchronous code inside of an asynchronous function.